# How to make this function testable?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, functional-programming

I have a function responsible for collecting a bunch of configurations and making a bigger configuration out of all these parts. So it's basically:

```
let applyUpdate updateData currentState =
    if not (someConditionAbout updateData) then
        log (SomeError)

    let this = getThis updateData currentState.Thingy
    let that = getThat updateData currentState.Thingy
    let andThat = createThatThing that this updateData

    // blablablablablabla

    { currentState with
        This = this
        That = that
        AndThat = andThat
        // etc. }
```

I currently have unit tests for `getThis`, `getThat`, `createThatThing`, but not for `applyUpdate`. I don't want to re-test what `getThis` and etc. are doing, I just want to test the logic specific to `applyUpdate` and just stub `getThis`. In an object-oriented style, these would be passed via an interface through dependency injection. In a functional style I'm unsure as to how to proceed:

```
// This is the function called by tests
let applyUpdateTestable getThisFn getThatFn createThatThingfn etc updateData currentState =
    if not (someConditionAbout updateData) then
        log (SomeError)

    let this = getThisFn updateData currentState.Thingy
    // etc

    { currentState with
        This = this
        // etc. }

// This is the function that is actually called by client code
let applyUpdate = applyUpdateTestable getThis getThat etc
```

This seems the functional equivalent of Bastard Injection, but beyond that I'm mainly concerned with:

- now my code is harder to follow because you can't just F12 (Go
  to Definition) into functions; this problem also exists with
  OO dependency injection but is mitigated by tooling (i.e. Resharper Go
  To Implementation).
- The function I'm testing isn't technically the one called by production code (there could be errors in the mapping)
- I don't even see a good name for that "Testable" version of the function
- I'm polluting the module with duplicate definitions of everything

How do deal with these problems in functional programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said:

> In an object-oriented style, these would be passed via an interface through dependency injection.

And the same approach is used in FP, but rather than injecting via the object constructor, you "inject" as parameters to the function.

So you are on the right track with your `applyUpdateTestable`, except that this would be also used as real code, not just as testable code.

For example, here's the function with the three extra dependencies passed in:

```
module Core =   
    let applyUpdate getThisFn getThatFn createThatThingfn updateData currentState =
        if not (someConditionAbout updateData) then
            log (SomeError)

        let this = getThisFn updateData currentState.Thingy
        // etc

        { currentState with
            This = this
            // etc. }
```

Then, in the "production" code, you inject the real dependencies:

```
module Production =         
    let applyUpdate updateData currentState = 
        Core.applyUpdate Real.getThis Real.getThat Real.createThatThingfn updateData currentState
```

or more simply, using partial application:

```
module Production =         
    let applyUpdate = 
        Core.applyUpdate Real.getThis Real.getThat Real.createThatThing
```

and in the test version, you inject the mocks or stubs instead:

```
module Test =       
    let applyUpdate = 
        Core.applyUpdate Mock.getThis Mock.getThat Mock.createThatThing
```

In the "production" example above, I statically hard-coded the dependencies on the `Real` functions, but alternatively,
just as with OO style dependency injection, the production `applyUpdate` could be created by some top-level coordinator
and then passed into the functions that need it.

This answers your questions, I hope:

- The same core code is used for both production and testing
- If you statically hard-code the dependencies, you can still use F12 to drill into them.

There are more complex versions of this approach, such as the "Reader" monad, but the above code is the simplest approach to start with.

Mark Seemann has a number of good posts on this topic, such as [Integration Testing](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/21/integration-testing-composed-functions/) and [SOLID: the next step is Functional](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional/) and [Ports and Adapters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/18/functional-architecture-is-ports-and-adapters/).

Comment: I love your site btw! I still have some concerns about this though:
- you still can't F12 from where the logic is written (the "Core"). And now you've moved the concrete functions in a different module so it's even harder to follow. But you did solve the pollution issue.
 - I'm curious what "standard" practice is; any examples of open-source F# code written in this style?

Comment: Thanks! It's true that you don't know what functions are being passed in to the core function (just the same as when interfaces are being passed into a class in OO). I've never understood the need for "goto implementation" myself, but you can do "find all references" on the core `applyUpdate` implementation and then, at the call sites where it is used, find out what functions are being passed to it. That's good enough, I hope :)

Comment: As to examples of good practice, chances are that they wouldn't be written in quite the same way as your example. The "core" code would tend to be small functions that only do one thing, which are then composed together. Something like "createRecord <!> getThis <*> getThat <*> createThatThing". I don't know if you've seen the "monadster" talk (https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/monadster/) but that presents some of these kinds of ideas.

Comment: Also, re the concrete functions being moved to a separate module, that would be analogous to having a "composition root" (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) where all the assembly is done. The core code knows nothing about how its dependencies are constructed. It's not really any different from how you would do it in OO, except that the granularity is at the function level rather than the object level.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Scott (@Grundoon) covers the more direct translation from OOP to FP. It's appropriate if you expect one of the `getThis`, `getThat` functions to be impure.

In general, passing functions as arguments to other functions is quite a functional thing to do (the receiving function is called a *higher-order function*, then), but it should be done in the interest of enabling variability. Adding extra function arguments only for testing purposes leads to what David Heinemeier Hansson calls [test-induced damage](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html).

In this answer, I'd like to offer another perspective, although I wish to stress that Scott's answer aligns with my own thinking (and that I've upvoted it). It fits F#, because F# is a hybrid language, and implicitly impure functions are possible.

In a strictly functional language (like Haskell), however, functions are [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) by default. If we assume that `getThis`, `getThat`, etcetera are all *referentially transparent* (pure), function calls can be replaced with their return values.

This means that you **don't have to replace them with Test Doubles**.

Instead, you can simply write your tests like this:

```
[<Fact>]
let testExample () =
    // Create updateData and currentState values here...

    let actual = applyUpdate updateData currentState

    let expected = 
        { currentState with
            This = getThis updateData currentState.Thingy
            That = getThat updateData currentState.Thingy
            // etc. }
    expected =! actual // assert that expected equals actual
```

You could argue that this test only duplicates the production code, but so would a test using OO-style Test Doubles. I assume that the real problem is more complex than the OP, which doesn't really seem to warrant a test of the `applyUpdate` function.

You could also argue that this test isn't a *unit* test, and I'd agree on the semantics; I call such tests [Facade Tests](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/06/27/FacadeTest).

[Pure functions are intrinsically testable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/07/functional-design-is-intrinsically-testable), so there's no reason to change their design to make them 'testable'.

Comment: The function does have non-trivial logic; I assumed I needed to stub the dependencies in order to test this logic in isolation. But looking at some of my tests I realize I did apply your approach in a few cases - it did feel awkward as I was writing it, coming from a strictly OOP background. Thanks for articulating why it can actually be a correct method!